# Jest: Material-UI: The `getOptionLabel` method of Autocomplete returned undefined instead of a string for {}

Tags: jestjs, material-ui, autocomplete, react-testing-library

I'm using react-testing library and jest. I'm trying to test user events from a component that consists of mui components.

When I run the below:

FilterBar.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import { MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core';
import FilterBar from '../../components/FilterBar';
import theme from '../../styles/theme';

FilterBar.test.js:
test('test filter function', () => {
  render(
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <FilterBar />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
  userEvent.click(screen.getByLabelText('fabButton'));
  screen.debug();
});
```

I receive this error(See image)

[image]
[image]

Here's the mui component(Autocomplete) giving the issue:

FilterDialog.test.js

```
  <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
            <List>
              <ListItem>
                <Autocomplete
                  value={tempLocationState}
                  id="combo-box-states"
                  options={stateList}
                  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.state}
                  getOptionSelected={(option) => option.state}
                  style={{ width: 230 }}
                  // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-props-no-spreading
                  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="State" />}
                  onChange={(event, state) => {
                    setTempLocationState(state);
                  }}
                />
              </ListItem>
```

When I remove this(see commented line)

```
   <Autocomplete
                  // value={tempLocationState}
                  id="combo-box-states"
                  options={stateList}
```

the test passes, but I want that default value to be present. I also noticed that while it passes when removing this line, data on this dialog is actually undefine in the screen.debug.

See below image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by passing the necessary props after mocking my childComponent

```
const mockFilterDialog = jest.fn();
jest.mock('../../components/FilterBar/FilterDialog', () => (props) => {
  mockFilterDialog(props);
  return <mock-FilterDialog />;
});

test('test filter function', () => {
  render(
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <FilterBar open locationState="Nigeria" />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
  userEvent.click(screen.getByLabelText('fabButton'));
  expect(mockFilterDialog).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
    expect.objectContaining({
      open: true,
      locationState: 'Nigeria',
    })
  );
});
screen.debug();
```